# Hide button on drop down selection -1

Tags: c#, button, drop-down-menu, visual-studio-2012

I need my create button to be hidden unless a facility is selected in my dropdown. When it is at -1 message i need my button to be hidden.

Code for button

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnCreate" runat="server" Text="Create New" Width="89px" Font-Size="X-Small" OnClick="btnCreate_Click" />
```

Drop down code

```
private void ResetForm()
{
    try
    {
        //facility dropdown
        ddlFacility2.Items.Clear();
        ddlFacility2.DataSource = this.DataLayer.model.MS_spGetFacilityInfo(null).OrderBy(x => x.FacilityName);
        ddlFacility2.DataTextField = "FacilityName";
        ddlFacility2.DataValueField = "FacilityID";
        ddlFacility2.DataBind();
        ddlFacility2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All Facility Records..", "-1"));

        BindGrid();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.SetMessage(ex.ToString(), PageMessageType.Error);
        AISLogger.WriteException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you update the question with what are you doing in page load event and droupdown list selected index change event?

Comment: Please add the correct tag (asp.net I think) so you don't confuse people

Comment: please add ddlFacility2 aspx page markup as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in first time page load if the default value selected is -1 you can set your button visible false as default.

in your droupdown list selected index change event you can enable/dissable button based on droupdown list selected value.

Comment: Don't forget the AutoPostBack="true" property on the DropDownList otherwise you will not refresh the page and the list will not be hidden

Comment: And also `if(!IsPostback){ResetForm();} `in the page load

Answer (score 1):

Add a `OnSelectedIndexChange` event to your dropdown list or add a clientside event to your dropdownlist. Double Click on your ddl you will see a function named `ddlFacility2_OnSelectedIndexChanged` in you code behind and add the below code to it.
Add `AutoPostBack=true` to you ddl

```
protected void ddlFacility2_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ddlFacility2.SelectedIndex>-1)
    {
        btnCreate.Enabled = true;
    }
                    else
    {
        btnCreate.Enabled = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wire up a JQuery script that can bind to your DropDownList's selected value...

In this example, the button's visibility is bound on a click from another button:

`$('#Button1').bind("click", function() {
    $("#Button2").hide();
});`

I dont know the exact syntax to use for the binding to selected value, but the above code should be a good place to start.